# Hide fields in Golang Gorm

Tags: json, go, go-gorm

I am using Gorm in my Golang project. Exctly I have a Rest-API and I get a request make the process and return an object, so, for example I have a struct User like this:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Password []byte
    Active bool
    Email string
    ActivationToken string
    RememberPasswordToken string
}
```

Now, when I create a User I am encoding it to JSON with:

```
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(user)
```

But in the client side I am receiving some fields that I don't really want to send/receive, for example: Created_At, Deleted_At, Updated_At, Password. So, what is the best way to ignore or hide that fields in the response? I saw that I can use a library called Reflect, but it seems to be a lot of work for a simple thing and I want to know if there's another way. Thank you very much

Comment: Either have separate models for what you're going to be returning and storing in the database, don't export the field, or you can use a json attribute to ignore the field i.e. `Password []byte \`json:'-'\``

Comment: @Gavin, is it even possible to change those attributes on an external struct?

Comment: @william.taylor.09 When was the struct mentioned to be external?

Comment: gorm.Model contains anonymous fields within the User struct. I'm assuming OP wants to restrict visibility to those fields.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 Ah, yeah you're right. I would probably make a separate model for the response then. That sounds like the easiest solution and also separates the database specific information from what the end user sees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Gavin said, I would suggest having two separate models and giving the model the ability to convert to the correct return type.

*models/user.go*

```
package models

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Password []byte
    Active bool
    Email string
    ActivationToken string
    RememberPasswordToken string
}

func (u *User) UserToUser() app.User {
    return app.User{
        Email: u.Email
    }
}
```

*app/user.go*

```
package app

type User struct {
    Email string
}
```

Comment: if we use preload/joins do we have to loop every object to convert it to other struct?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to have a fixed object to return, you can change the tags with `json:"-"` to decide the elements to send with json.
For the elements in the gorm.Model:

```
type Model struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time `sql:"index"`
}
```

You can substitute them for your own struct:

```
type OwnModel struct {
    ID        uint       `gorm:"primary_key"`
    CreatedAt time.Time  `json:"-"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time  `json:"-"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time `json:"-";sql:"index"`
}
```

So, your User struct would be like that:

```
type User struct {
    OwnModel
    Password []byte
    Active bool
    Email string
    ActivationToken string
    RememberPasswordToken string
}

The other User fields is your decision to add or not `json:"-"` tag.
```

Answer (score 13):

For me helped add `json:"-"` to gorm.Model

For example:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model `json:"-"`
    Password []byte
    Active bool
    Email string
    ActivationToken string
    RememberPasswordToken string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to hide the relation to my User model from my Sessions model by creating an inherited struct with an `omitempty`

```golang
// Trick to hide the User assocation from the results
type Session struct {
    models.Session
    User *models.User `json:"User,omitempty"`
}

func Token(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    user := auth.User(c)
    var sessions []Session
    database.Db.Find(&sessions, "user_id = ?", user.ID)
    return render.Render(c, sessions)
}
```

I hope this helps - i also added a feature request - i think this would be great built-in to gorm

https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/5746

Answer (score -2):

```golang
type OrmModel struct {
    gorm.Model `json:"-"`
    ID        uint  `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id,omitempty"`
}
type User struct {
    OrmModel
    Password []byte
    Active bool
    Email string
    ActivationToken string
    RememberPasswordToken string
}
```